# Limit decimal digits in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to restrict typing more than 4 decimal digits in textbox, Can anybody help me on this please?

```
<input type="text" class="txt" id="txtValue"  ng-model="serviceParam.Value">
```

important thing is, validation should happen when typing and not focus-out(tab out).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="txt" id="txtValue"  ng-model="serviceParam.Value" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==5) return false;">
```

use below code. it'll return false if char is > 4

Comment: output should be 121.3456  . when trying to type any more decimal digit after .3456 then it should restrict

Answer (score 0):

Follow up this code, it will disable the input after four decimal places. You need to use `ng-change` to follow up the changes after decimal places. I guess this covers all your requirement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="decimal">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
<input type="text" ng-model="number_value" ng-change="setFourDecimalPlaces()" ng-maxlength={{maxlength}} ng-disabled="disabled" />
{{decimal_change}}
<script>
    angular.module('decimal', [])
    .controller('ExampleController',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.disabled = false;
    $scope.setFourDecimalPlaces = function(){
      $scope.decimal_change = $scope.number_value.split(".");
      if(undefined !== $scope.decimal_change[1] && $scope.decimal_change[1].length) {
          if($scope.decimal_change[1].length >= 4){
            $scope.maxlength = $scope.decimal_change.length
          }
      }
    }
}])
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Disabling the control will not suite my requirement.

Comment: @guru In that case you can limit the max length. check the updated answer

Comment: @guru Just for record please consider accepting solution in case if I helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.. but doesn't help me. because i could not set maxlength also. user may enter 1234567.0987 . So, the validation should happen for numbers after "."

Comment: @guru You can set maxlength upto 100 or 200 that doesn't matter

Comment: How this textbox can be enabled back?

Comment: you don't need to disable it. that was just an example. even if you leave it it will consider only four decimal places. you can remove this line of code `$scope.disabled = true` to not allow it to disable

Comment: You can see in the above code it's allowing you to enter your digit but only accepting four decimal places